# How to force Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue to use web proxy?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I'm creating a daemon application that will connect to SharePoint Online using CSOM. My application will be running in corporate environment behind an internet proxy. I'm using standard SharePoint Add-in model with TokenHelper and SharePointContext classes provided, that use Microsoft.IdentityModel.Extensions.dll.

I have rigged the TokenHelper to use proxy in two places:  WebRequest in GetRealmFromTargetUrl and a WebClient in AcsMetadataParser.

Yet it doesn't work as it seems to me that the DLL uses yet another web request. Here are the StackTraces from an execution that triggered exception:

```
Exception Message: Token request failed.
Stack Trace:    
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)
   at ScriptTask_d38d98a4cb054097ac7c2ece4802bf9a.spo.TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(String targetPrincipalName, String targetHost, String targetRealm)
   at ScriptTask_d38d98a4cb054097ac7c2ece4802bf9a.ScriptMain.Main()

Inner Exception Message: Unable to connect to the remote server
Inner Stack Trace:    
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2WebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Protocols.OAuth2.OAuth2S2SClient.Issue(String securityTokenServiceUrl, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request)
```

I wonder if there is a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got around it.

Instead of this call:

```
oauth2Response = 
    client.Issue(AcsMetadataParser.GetStsUrl(targetRealm), 
    oauth2Request) as OAuth2AccessTokenResponse;
```

I've created a static method IssueToken and a dummy "mapping" class with the following code:

```
private static OAuth2AccessTokenResponse IssueToken(string sts, OAuth2AccessTokenRequest oauth2Request) {
    string requestString = "grant_type=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauth2Request.GrantType) +
                            "&client_id=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauth2Request.ClientId) +
                            "&client_secret=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauth2Request.ClientSecret) +
                            "&resource=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(oauth2Request.Resource);

    string tokenResponse;

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestString);

    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(sts);
    request.Proxy = new System.Net.WebProxy { Address = new Uri(InternetProxy) };
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    using (Stream reqStream = request.GetRequestStream()) {
        reqStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    }
    using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
        using (Stream respStream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(respStream)) {
                tokenResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    OAuth2AccessTokenResponseDummy dummy = jss.Deserialize<OAuth2AccessTokenResponseDummy>(tokenResponse);

    OAuth2AccessTokenResponse oauth2Response = new OAuth2AccessTokenResponse () {
        TokenType = dummy.token_type,
        ExpiresIn = dummy.expires_in,
        NotBefore = jss.Deserialize<DateTime>(@"""\/Date(" + dummy.not_before + @")\/""").ToLocalTime(),
        ExpiresOn = jss.Deserialize<DateTime>(@"""\/Date(" + dummy.expires_on + @")\/""").ToLocalTime(),
        Scope = dummy.resource,
        AccessToken = dummy.access_token
    };

    return oauth2Response;
}

private class OAuth2AccessTokenResponseDummy {
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public string expires_in { get; set; }
    public string not_before { get; set; }
    public string expires_on { get; set; }
    public string resource { get; set; }
    public string access_token { get; set; }
}
```

And also I've added web proxy into GetClientContextWithAccessToken's delegate:

```
public static ClientContext GetClientContextWithAccessToken(string targetUrl, string accessToken) {
    ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(targetUrl);

    clientContext.AuthenticationMode = ClientAuthenticationMode.Anonymous;
    clientContext.FormDigestHandlingEnabled = false;
    clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest +=
        delegate(object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs) {
            webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.RequestHeaders["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
            webRequestEventArgs.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Proxy = webProxy;
        };

    return clientContext;
}
```

Comment: What is webProxy and InternetProxy. and how to use this methods ? can you pleaes ealaborate? I am having the same issues

Comment: `var webProxy = new System.Net.WebProxy { Address = new Uri(InternetProxy) };`
and InternetProxy is an address of your proxy, like `http://proxy.domain.com:8080`